Wrapper for calling Python + tee
I currently use a bash script to wrap the call to my program and log all outputs into a txt file:
python -u myscript.py args 2>&1 | tee -a outdir/log.txt

The problem is outdir may depend on args and bash is too simplistic to handle this.  Is there:

An internal Python substitute for tee that will allow me to get rid of the wrapper script and log everything directly in Python?

Can I create a Python wrapper script that mimics the above bash, wraps the call to python and tee, and has the brains to figure out where outdir is based on the args? (I could reuse parts of my main script for this)


I'd prefer option #1 if possible.

Regarding option 1, are you fine with ignoring exceptions and other messages that come from the Python interpreter and not the program itself?

@wjandrea, so far it's been somewhat handy to include these for debugging crashes.  I use this to log a deep learning training process that can run for a while and sometimes breaks.

What is args exactly and why can't bash handle it?

option 2

Can I create a Python wrapper script that mimics the above bash, wraps the call to python and tee, and has the brains to figure out where outdir is based on the args? (I could reuse parts of my main script for this)

If the original script is a short run-once thing, not something
that will keep running and generating a stream, it is simple
import os, sys
from pathlib import Path)

original_script, *args = sys.argv[1:]

# assume outdir is the first of the args:
outdir = Path(args[0])

# just run the code
output_data = os.popen(" ".join(["python -u", original_script, *args])).read()
with open(outdir / "log.txt", "at") as f:
    f.write(output_data)

print(output_data)


option 1
If the script is intended to produce a continous stream, them the better approach might be to modify it and configure logging - so that the output is sent to wherever you want - you´d have to change print statements for logger.info - but then you can also get timestamps, and other metadata for free for each output line.
Python's stdlib logging package can do it in a multi-step configuration - but nowadaysI resort to use the loguru 3rd party lib which can ease the job:
# myscript.py
# (`pip install loguru` before running)
import sys

from loguru import logger

#assume outdir is the first arg
outdir = sys.argv[1]

logger.add(outdir + "/log.txt")  # optionally add `format="{message}"` parameter to not add any metadata such as timestamps.

...

logger.info("myoutput message)

option 1 with no 3rd party lib, no code changes
And finally, modifying some code prefix, without having to change "print" calls, you can monkeypatch the sys.stdout stream so that it streams both to stdout and the desired file.
(this could be combined with using loguru, should you like it for a larger project)
#myscript.py

import sys

class NewOut:
     def __init__(self, outputpath):
          self.outputpath = outputpath
     def write(self, message):
          with open(self.outputpath, "at") as f:
              f.write(message)
          sys.__stdout__.write(message)

     def flush(self):
         sys.__stdout__.flush()
          
outputdir = sys.argv[1]

# replace original stdout:

sys.stdout = NewOut(outputdir + /"log.txt")

# rest of your code:

...



rants on a proper solution for option 2
Unfortunatelly, back to "solution 2", having a new script that could wrap the initial script call, and handle a long stream of data as it goes is a bit more complicated, and I can't type it here by heart, as the above snippets. It is doable in 1-2 hours, with some research os the stdlib
subprocess.Popen class - but that thing is so worried in covering all possible edge cases, it is hard to use - and correctly partial communication (i.e. fetching a subprocess output as it happens) is not exemplified in the docs. It involves manually creating the pipe through an os.pipe call and managing those to get the data out of the subprocess without saturating the data
Back to (1), since implementing proper tee in Python is hard, it is not hard to embed a call to tee inside your script itself, so that when it detects it is output is the console, it reruns itself but with a command line including the tee output:
#myscript.py

import sys
if sys.stdout.isatty():  # output is directly to the terminal
    import os
    outputdir = sys.argv[1]
    result = os.system("python -u " + " ".join(sys.argv) + f"|tee -a {outputdir}/log.txt")
    sys.exit(result)
# rest of your code 
...



Wow, thank you @jsbueno, this is plenty to chew on and I'll have to try these in piecemeal fashion. My script runs a lengthy training process, which eventually ends.  I believe that means it's not a continuous stream, right?

it means it is a continuous stream for the purposes of these examples: all output would only be displayed at the end of the process, and that my first option 2 session won´t work. Any of the solutions in options 1 would work - if you can use loguru, just go for that.
